# regex text between two string python

Tags: python, regex

I have some text like this:

```
CustomerID:1111,

text1

CustomerID:2222,

text2

CustomerID:3333,

text3

CustomerID:4444,

text4

CustomerID:5555,

text5
```

Each text has multiple lines.

I want to store the customer id and the text for each id in tuples (e.g. `(1111, text1)`, `(2222, text2)`, etc).

First, I use the expression below:

```
re.findall('CustomerID:(\d+)(.*?)CustomerID:', rawtxt, re.DOTALL)
```

However, I only get `(1111, text1)`, `(3333, text3)`, `(5555, text5)`.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'CustomerID:(\d+),\s*(.*?)\s*(?=CustomerID:|$)', rawtxt, re.DOTALL)
```

Findall returns only the `groups`. use a `lookahead` for stopping the `non greedy` quantifier.Its also suggested to use `r` or `raw` mode to specify your regexes.If you dont use `lookahead` then `customerid` for next match will be consumed and so next match will not present.Overlapping matches has to be removed by using `lookahead` which do not consume `string`

Comment: what is the function of `re.DOTALL`

Comment: @SIslam `.` be default does not match `\n` or `newline`.With this flag it does.So now `.*` will match mulitline

Comment: Ah! here with and without `re.DOTALL` prints the same!

Comment: @SIslam because we are covering `\n` or `newlines` with `\s`

Comment: So in this case do we need `re.DOTALL`? Thanks

Comment: @SIslam yes if `text3` is `test 3 asas \n asddsa` something of this sort

Answer (score 2):

Actually no need regex here:

```
>>> with open('file') as f:
...     rawtxt = [i.strip() for i in f if i != '\n']
...     
>>> l = []
>>> for i in [rawtxt[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(rawtxt), 2)]:
...     l.append((i[0][11:-1], i[1]))
...     
... 
>>> l
[('1111', 'text1'), ('2222', 'text2'), ('3333', 'text3'), ('4444', 'text4'), ('5
555', 'text5')]
>>>
```

If you need `1111`, `2222`, etc. be int, use `l.append((int(i[0][11:-1]), i[1]))` instead of `l.append((i[0][11:-1], i[1]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> txt='''\
... CustomerID:1111,
... 
... text1
... 
... CustomerID:2222,
... 
... text2
... 
... CustomerID:3333,
... 
... text3
... 
... CustomerID:4444,
... 
... text4
... 
... CustomerID:5555,
... 
... text5'''
```

You can do:

```
>>> [re.findall(r'^(\d+),\s+(.+)', block) for block in txt.split('CustomerID:') if block]
[[('1111', 'text1')], [('2222', 'text2')], [('3333', 'text3')], [('4444', 'text4')], [('5555', 'text5')]]
```

If it is multiline text, you can do:

```
>>> [re.findall(r'^(\d+),\s+([\s\S]+)', block) for block in txt.split('CustomerID:') if block]
[[('1111', 'text1\n\n')], [('2222', 'text2\n\n')], [('3333', 'text3\n\n')], [('4444', 'text4\n\n')], [('5555', 'text5')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple one may be-

```
>>>re.findall(r'(\b\d+\b),\s*(\btext\d+\b)', rawtxt)
>>>[('1111', 'text1'), ('2222', 'text2'), ('3333', 'text3'), ('4444', 'text4'), ('5555', 'text5')]
```

Edit-
If needed (for worse ordered data) use `filter`

```
filter(lambda x: len(x)>1,re.findall(r'(\b\d+\b),\s*(\btext\d+\b)', rawtxt))
```

**SEE DEMO**
[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/fD2sW6/1)

Answer (score 0):

re.findall is not the best tool for this, since regex is always greedy and will try to gobble up all the subsequent customerID's with the text.

A tool practically created for this is re.split. Brackets capture the id number and filter out "CustomerID". A second line stitches tokens into tuples the way you wanted:

```
toks = re.split(r'CustomerID:(\d{4}),\n', t)
zip(toks[1::2],toks[2::2])
```

EDIT: corrected index in zip(). Sample output after correction:

```
[('1111', 'text1\n'),
 ('2222', 'text2\n'),
 ('3333', 'text3\n'),
 ('4444', 'text4\n'),
 ('5555', 'text5')]
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants, your expression returns `[('1111', '2222'), ('2222', '3333'), ('3333', '4444'), ('4444', '5555')]`

Comment: @SIslam ... toks[2::2] instead of toks[3::2]. I will correct it